# How to write a nested dictionary to a JSON file with specific format?

Tags: python, json

```py
container = {'15/09/2021': {'a': '5', 'b': '7', 'c': '9', 'd': 'missing', 'e': '18'}, '16/09/2021': {'a': '6', 'b': '7', 'c': '9', 'd': '10', 'e': '12'}, '17/09/2021': {'a': '7', 'b': '8', 'c': '10', 'd': '11', 'e': 'missing'}, '18/09/2021': {'a': '9', 'b': '12', 'c': '15', 'd': 'missing', 'e': 'missing'}}    
with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(container, outfile, indent=4)
```

The result I'm getting :

[image: The result I'm getting]

This is the desired result :

[image: This is the desired result]

Comment: Ok but those are the same pictures ? Its the same json format  on both.

Answer (score 2):

I think both pictures are the same JSON, only thing is different it is the indentation.

Comment: Yes, they are the same JSON, what I wanted is to have the output , with the specified indentation. when I write to the file, without having to go to the file and edit the indentations